# How to write Subset ⊆ in an operation

Tags: vb.net, boolean, logic, subset, contains

I want to perform logic operation to check if a string or a set of numbers is contained in a variable. In the same manner simply write:

```
a + b 
a * b
a = b
```

Is there a way to write something like:

```
a ⊆ b
```

I expect te retrieve a boolean result out of it, stating true or false to determine if it is contained in the other variable. I am writing a comparison tool and would like to simplify it to use a math or logic operator instead of a method like InStr().

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ for this:

```
Dim bContainsAllA As Boolean = Not a.Except(b).Any()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create new operators... Your options is to use an existing operator, create a method or do an extension method.

I wouldn't recommend using InStr since this is old VB. There are good methods in the String class. Or use LINQ.